# Can't make QTcpSocket/QTcpServer work together

Tags: c++, qt4.8, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm trying to understand how QTcpSocket and QTcpServer works together. So I wrote this simple example, which starts server and client socket on localhost:

```
QTcpServer server;
qDebug() << "Listen: " << server.listen( QHostAddress::Any, 10590);

usleep( 500000); //1/2 sec

QTcpSocket client;
client.connectToHost( QHostAddress( "127.0.0.1"), 10590);

usleep( 5000000);
qDebug() << "Client socket available: " << client.isValid();
qDebug() << "Pending connections:" << server.hasPendingConnections();
```

And I got this output:

```
Listen:  true 
Client socket available:  true 
Pending connections false
```

Why there is no pending connections?

PS> I don't wanna use SLOT/SIGNALS mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main( )
{
  QTcpServer server;
  qDebug() << "Listen: " << server.listen( QHostAddress::Any, 10590);

  usleep( 5000000);

  QTcpSocket client;
  client.connectToHost( QHostAddress( "127.0.0.1"), 10590);

  usleep( 5000000);

  qDebug() << "Client socket connected: " << ( client.state( ) == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState );
  qDebug() << "Pending connections:" << server.hasPendingConnections();
}
```

Output:

```
Listen:  true
Client socket connected:  false
Pending connections: false
```

This is because `QTcpServer` cannot answer to `QTcpSocket` query... both are on same thread and if `QTcpSocket` is executing, `QTcpServer` is on idle.

Try it in multi-thread app.

Comment: Thank you @eferion, I didn't know that they can't live in one thread.